# How to read element by element an array inside an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I want to calculate the MSE of between two vectors, the original one and a prediction.
X_train is a vector with all the original inputs and reconstructed32 are all the predictions, but I only want to calculate the MSE for the first element (X_train[0] and its prediction reconstructed32[0]), and I want do do it manually using some sort of function as the following:

```
mse=[]
for coef, coef32 in zip(X_train[0], reconstructed32[0]):
    mse.append((coef-coef32)**2)
print("MSE is", np.mean(mse))
```

But coef and coef32 do not access all the coefficients of the vector, instead they take the full vector and the for does only one iteration.
This is how X_train[0] looks like:

```
array([[0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 2.26577651e-02, 4.44901595e-03,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        1.19896736e-02, 2.88007129e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        1.89431056e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 3.64951454e-02, 0.00000000e+00,
        3.19024414e-01, 7.74396257e-03, 6.00360870e-01, 0.00000000e+00,
        6.25879224e-03, 6.58161461e-01, 8.55771124e-01, 0.00000000e+00,
        9.72116515e-02, 1.20666134e-03, 1.45429194e-01, 0.00000000e+00,
        8.25748563e-01, 6.86123502e-03, 5.37337780e-01, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 5.24137542e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 3.74730385e-04,
        0.00000000e+00, 1.18224040e-01, 8.56024176e-02, 0.00000000e+00,
        2.49160156e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 8.91805351e-01, 2.61418521e-03,
        0.00000000e+00, 1.73141190e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 4.95929737e-04,
        0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 4.93207388e-02, 5.37037617e-03,
        3.81159922e-03, 2.94345170e-01, 4.77780886e-02, 0.00000000e+00,
        5.86739518e-02, 1.02838585e-02, 1.41941339e-01, 3.23100435e-03,
        0.00000000e+00, 1.34332031e-01, 2.35870923e-03, 0.00000000e+00,
        5.09367557e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 1.07753032e-03, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 3.47328931e-01, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 2.65773922e-01, 1.57823116e-02, 5.41949784e-03,
        7.56190493e-05, 1.40293926e-01, 5.02460590e-03, 6.51085284e-03,
        9.38402303e-03, 2.63461888e-01, 1.96186375e-04, 1.39610067e-01,
        0.00000000e+00, 2.39743218e-02, 3.54982950e-02, 6.54916763e-02,
        5.11557400e-01, 3.56561318e-03, 5.72423302e-02, 0.00000000e+00,
        1.21502653e-01, 2.71597654e-02, 2.47318600e-03, 6.85532205e-03,
        5.31266391e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 2.94529963e-02,
        0.00000000e+00, 3.75285745e-01, 3.31357837e-01, 1.18085509e-03,
        1.19613800e-02, 6.72158494e-05, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 7.86180317e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        4.27392730e-03, 2.27557942e-02, 1.35929761e-02, 1.27607910e-02,
        0.00000000e+00, 2.63269083e-03, 1.48336608e-02, 0.00000000e+00,
        1.77292936e-02, 1.18409727e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 5.49420249e-03,
        0.00000000e+00, 1.70363311e-03, 1.75287843e-01, 4.07821295e-04]],
      dtype=float32)
```

As an example, if I try this simple code:

```
for coef in X_train[0]:
    print("coef is", coef)
```

I get this output:

```
coef is [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 2.26577651e-02 4.44901595e-03
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 1.19896736e-02 2.88007129e-03 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 1.89431056e-01 0.00000000e+00 3.64951454e-02 0.00000000e+00
 3.19024414e-01 7.74396257e-03 6.00360870e-01 0.00000000e+00
 6.25879224e-03 6.58161461e-01 8.55771124e-01 0.00000000e+00
 9.72116515e-02 1.20666134e-03 1.45429194e-01 0.00000000e+00
 8.25748563e-01 6.86123502e-03 5.37337780e-01 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 5.24137542e-03 0.00000000e+00 3.74730385e-04
 0.00000000e+00 1.18224040e-01 8.56024176e-02 0.00000000e+00
 2.49160156e-02 0.00000000e+00 8.91805351e-01 2.61418521e-03
 0.00000000e+00 1.73141190e-03 0.00000000e+00 4.95929737e-04
 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 4.93207388e-02 5.37037617e-03
 3.81159922e-03 2.94345170e-01 4.77780886e-02 0.00000000e+00
 5.86739518e-02 1.02838585e-02 1.41941339e-01 3.23100435e-03
 0.00000000e+00 1.34332031e-01 2.35870923e-03 0.00000000e+00
 5.09367557e-03 0.00000000e+00 1.07753032e-03 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 3.47328931e-01 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 2.65773922e-01 1.57823116e-02 5.41949784e-03
 7.56190493e-05 1.40293926e-01 5.02460590e-03 6.51085284e-03
 9.38402303e-03 2.63461888e-01 1.96186375e-04 1.39610067e-01
 0.00000000e+00 2.39743218e-02 3.54982950e-02 6.54916763e-02
 5.11557400e-01 3.56561318e-03 5.72423302e-02 0.00000000e+00
 1.21502653e-01 2.71597654e-02 2.47318600e-03 6.85532205e-03
 5.31266391e-01 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 2.94529963e-02
 0.00000000e+00 3.75285745e-01 3.31357837e-01 1.18085509e-03
 1.19613800e-02 6.72158494e-05 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 7.86180317e-01 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 4.27392730e-03 2.27557942e-02 1.35929761e-02 1.27607910e-02
 0.00000000e+00 2.63269083e-03 1.48336608e-02 0.00000000e+00
 1.77292936e-02 1.18409727e-04 0.00000000e+00 5.49420249e-03
 0.00000000e+00 1.70363311e-03 1.75287843e-01 4.07821295e-04]
```

And I would like to get "coef is" in front of every coefficient, not in front of the full vector. How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your code to generate `X_train`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
for coef in X_train[0][0]:
    print("coef is", coef)
```

Comment: But his array looks like a 2D-array, so `X_train[0]` should work?!

Comment: `X_train[0]` only gets the first element of the array and prints that

Comment: `X_train = np.random.rand(1,10); for coef in X_train[0]: print("coef is", coef)` works for me

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate through a NumPy array, you are iterating through the first index (i.e. the rows). Since you have a matrix of dimension `(1, d)`, so iterating gives you the whole first row.

A few ways you can fix this, but the easiest way is just to do it with the row vector itself (of dimension `(d,)`).

```py
# in your case, your_idx is 0
for coef, coef32 in zip(X_train[your_idx][0], reconstructed32[your_idx][0]):
   ... # do your thing
```